# Getting the issue in cloudera 4.7.. WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Could not configure sink c1 due to: No channel configured for sink: c1

Tags: bigdata

Below is the conf file

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = k1
a1.sinks = c1

a1.sources.r1.type = netcat
a1.sources.r1.bind = localhost
a1.sources.r1.port = 44444


a1.sinks.c1.type = logger


a1.channels.k1.type = memory
a1.channels.k1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.k1.transactionCapacity = 100


a1.sources.r1.channels = k1
a1.sources.c1.channel = k1
```

The log file shows below warning.

```
14/10/21 07:14:44 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: c1 Agent: a1
14/10/21 07:14:44 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:c1
14/10/21 07:14:45 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Could not configure sink  c1 due to: No channel configured for sink: c1
org.apache.flume.conf.ConfigurationException: No channel configured for sink: c1
    at org.apache.flume.conf.sink.SinkConfiguration.configure(SinkConfiguration.java:51)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSinks(FlumeConfiguration.java:680)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.isValid(FlumeConfiguration.java:346)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.access$000(FlumeConfiguration.java:212)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:126)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.<init>(FlumeConfiguration.java:108)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.getFlumeConfiguration(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:193)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
14/10/21 07:14:45 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [a1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It shoud be

```
a1.sinks.c1.channel = k1
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be this

```
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1  
a1.sinks.k1.channel= c1
```